# Bash Script not executed

Tags: bash

I have this little bash script :

```
  #!/bin/bash

  PATH1="/home/user100/files"
  CMD1=$(find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec rm -fr {} +;)
  cd $PATH1
  $CMD1
```

If I run one by one the commands they are all executed successfully, if I run the script it just does nothing at all.

Any help or idea would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the contents of the `CMD1` variable? Replace `$CMD1` in the last line with `echo "$CMD1"`. Probably you are doing something very wrong...

Comment: You now deleted all .sh files from below your current location. Hopefully it was not `/` or `~`.

Comment: It runs the find in `.`, your cwd, and removes any .sh files in there. (Being as find recurses, and you picked files and not directories, the -r in remove is junk.) Anyway, that find returns nothing - it does the commands, but there is no data from stdout. So CMD1 is empty. Then you cd to another directory, and run an empty command. What exactly did you intend it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to store a command as string in a variable you shouldn't use $()

```
 CMD1="find . -type f -iname '*.sh' -exec rm -fr {} +;"
```

Then you call the variable later using  `eval` command..
So your script should be something like:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  PATH1="/home/user100/files"
  CMD1="find . -type f -iname '*.sh' -exec rm -fr {} +;"
  cd $PATH1
  eval $CMD1;
```

Then don't forget to give execute permission for the script

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Then run the script

```
./script.sh
```

Comment: `exec` will never run with arguments if you don't use `eval `

Comment: You're absolutely right! it chokes on the internal quoting without the eval as well.

Comment: Without `eval`, `find ... exec` throws an error because of the (unneeded) semicolon in `+;`, which is not seen as a control operator when resulting from an expansion and thus prevents `find` from recognizing the `+`. Assuming we have reasons for executing a command as a result of parameter expansion (which are not evident here), the risks from `eval` can be avoided by using an array, e.g. `cmd=( find ... '*.sh' ... {} + ); "${cmd[@]}"` as Kusalananda pointed out in comments to a now-deleted answer. (Sorry for reposting, my previous comment included a major mistake).